# how to send a PUT request with experss.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently learning node.js
And I have a question about PUT request

I can create the object
And see it in the URL
But I do not know how to write a request to edit it
For example change the price of the vehicle?
I would love to know how to write the edit request

this my HTML code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add car to the storege</h1>
    <form action="/addCar" method="post">

    <label for="">Car model</label>
        <input name="car_model" type="text">
    <label for="">Color</label>
        <input name="color" type="text">
    <label for="">Engine capacity</label>
        <input name='Engine' type="number">
    <label for="">Price</label>
        <input name='price' type="number">
    <label for="">id</label>
        <input name='id' type="number">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">

    </form>
</body>
</html>


 const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3002
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

let carStorege = []

app.post('/addCar', (req,res) => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        car_model: Joi.string().required(),
        color: Joi.string().required(),
        Engine: Joi.number().required(),
        id: Joi.number().required(),
        price: Joi.number().required()
    })
    const validation = schema.validate(req.body)
    if(validation.error){
        res.send('something worng!')
    }
    carStorege.push(req.body)
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send('<h1>Upload success !</h1>')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/addCar.html')
})

app.get('/carStorege', (req, res)=> {
    res.send(carStorege)
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/carStorge.html')
})

// put requset to edit the object..


app.listen(port, () => console.log('srever is live'))
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You say you want to **send** a PUT request with Express, but the place you put the comment suggests you want to **receive** a PUT request there. Which is it? You don't have any code to send **or** receive one at the moment.

Comment: Why do you want to use a PUT request to edit something when you have already used a POST request to create something? Consistency is  virtue.

Comment: The code I wrote down is part of practice.  I need to create an object and then edit it .. I would love to hear another way to edit besides requesting PUT

Comment: Use POST like you already do for creation…

Answer (score 0):

send a PUT request with experss.js

use `methodOverride`  and  `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />`

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Add car to the storege</h1>
    <form action="/addCar" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
        <label for="">Car model</label>
        <input name="car_model" type="text">
        <label for="">Color</label>
        <input name="color" type="text">
        <label for="">Engine capacity</label>
        <input name='Engine' type="number">
        <label for="">Price</label>
        <input name='price' type="number">
        <label for="">id</label>
        <input name='id' type="number">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">

    </form>
</body>

</html>

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3002
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(methodOverride(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
        // look in urlencoded POST bodies and delete it
        console.log('sss');
        var method = req.body._method
        delete req.body._method
        return method
    }
}))
let carStorege = []

app.post('/addCar', (req, res) => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        car_model: Joi.string().required(),
        color: Joi.string().required(),
        Engine: Joi.number().required(),
        id: Joi.number().required(),
        price: Joi.number().required()
    })
    const validation = schema.validate(req.body)
    if (validation.error) {
        res.send('something worng!')
    }
    carStorege.push(req.body)
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send('<h1>Upload success !</h1>')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/addCar.html')
})

app.get('/carStorege', (req, res) => {
    res.send(carStorege)
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/carStorge.html')
})

app.put('/addCar', function (req, res) {
    var car = req.car;
    console.log(req.car)
    res.send('<h1>sss success !</h1>')
    //do update
});




app.listen(port, () => console.log('srever is live'))
```

Comment: I still get the Cannot GET / addCar error

Comment: @snir.hak — That would be because you are making a GET request. It doesn't do much good to support receiving PUT requests if you don't make one.

Comment: app.put('/addCar', function (req, res) {
    var car = req.car;
    console.log(req.car)
    res.send('<h1>sss success !</h1>')
    //do update
}); this is not put request?

Comment: @snir.hak `app.put` is put request. `app.post` is post request

Comment: I still have no answer to the question